# Facebook Graph Api Feed not returning all posts

Tags: c#, .net, facebook

I have a problem when I read "/feed" information via Graph Api of one of my friend profile, as example. 
I can get some posts, but especially share links and aplications post pictures, like Instagram , aren't returned by graph api.

In opposite, I can see all them in Timeline of this friend that I testing. Is not a public permission, because is showing in timeline (inside facebook page) for me.

I also tried "/post" and "/home" and the same.

I know facebook blocks public content, but in this case, is my friend profile and I can see everything in Timeline, how I couldn't see in Facebook Graph Api "/feed" return?

PS: All permissions, linke read_stream is was gave by application

Answer (score 0):

It could be your friend's privacy settings that is preventing you from seeing such activity. You can see what information you share via the Graph API youself by going to `Privacy Settings` > `Apps, games and websites` and editing the `How people bring your info to apps they use` section.

The `My app activity` option could be unchecked by your friends, which is why you cannot see activity from other apps in the API.